# Is there any Custom Control for Music Visualizer in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am finding to show music `Visualizer` in my music app.

Apple doesn't support for music Visualizer.

I am using `MPMusicPlayerController's` `iPodMusicPlayer`.

Is there any `framework` or `controls` or `SDK` for music `Visualizer`?

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: check this [link](https://github.com/ChiefPilot/F3BarGauge)

Comment: thz.but that's is not music Visualizer :)

Comment: you can customize that one

Comment: try this: [iOS Audio Visualizer](https://github.com/prodia/AudioVisualizer)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the waveform, then you could try this:
https://github.com/gyetvan-andras/cocoa-waveform

Comment: thz . i have been already tried it. It's just a trick with Wave Image.:) not a waveform

Comment: Maybe you can do the visualisation using this: https://github.com/mike-dutka/gl-data-visualization-view